# d3.js Map not Showing

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have been trying to create a basic map using d3.js with a world shapefile I downloaded (ne_50m_admin_0_countries). I have been trying for hours with all sorts of different code to try and get it to display, but I always end up with a blank HTML page. I am a new to d3.js and am pretty amateur. Here is the code I have been trying to get to work, it is from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4180634

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  background: #fcfcfa;
}

    .stroke {
      fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.fill {
  fill: #fff;
}

.graticule {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #777;
  stroke-width: .5px;
  stroke-opacity: .5;
}

.land {
  fill: #222;
}

.boundary {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: .5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.geo.projection.v0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
height = 580;

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var projection = d3.geo.kavrayskiy7()
    .scale(170)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    .precision(.1);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var graticule = d3.geo.graticule();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.append("defs").append("path")
    .datum({type: "Sphere"})
    .attr("id", "sphere")
    .attr("d", path);

svg.append("use")
    .attr("class", "stroke")
    .attr("xlink:href", "#sphere");

svg.append("use")
    .attr("class", "fill")
    .attr("xlink:href", "#sphere");

svg.append("path")
    .datum(graticule)
    .attr("class", "graticule")
    .attr("d", path);

d3.json("world-110.json", function(error, name) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var countries = topojson.feature(name, world.objects.countries).features,
      neighbors = topojson.neighbors(world.objects.countries.geometries);

  svg.selectAll(".country")
      .data(name)
    .enter().insert("path", ".graticule")
      .attr("class", "country")
      .attr("d", path)
      .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(d.color = d3.max(neighbors[i], function(n) { return countries[n].color; }) + 1 | 0); });

  svg.insert("path", ".graticule")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(name, world.objects.countries, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("class", "boundary")
      .attr("d", path);
});

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");

</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

It seems like my JSON isn't working for any of them, but I saved it properly through QGIS. Here is an excerpt of it:

```
{"type":"Topology","transform":{"scale":[0.03600360036003601,0.017366249624962495],"translate":[-180,-90]},"objects":{"land":{"type":"MultiPolygon","arcs":[[[0]],[[1]],[[2]],[[3]],[[4]],[[5]],[[6]],[[
```

Any guidance as to what I may be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to copy the code again from the original website.

The code in your post differs in several lines from the one on http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4180634

E.g. you are using parameter `name` instead of `world` but are still trying to access a `world` variable which must be undefined:

```
// YOUR CODE:
d3.json("world-110.json", function(error, name) {
    if (error) throw error;

    var countries = topojson.feature(name, world.objects.countries).features, // world is UNDEFINED here
        neighbors = topojson.neighbors(world.objects.countries.geometries);
-----------------------------------------------------
// ORIGINAL:
d3.json("./world-50m.json", function(error, world) {
    if (error) throw error;

    var countries = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features,
        neighbors = topojson.neighbors(world.objects.countries.geometries);
```

I just copied the code from the website and the according json from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4090846/world-50m.json and it is working fine and showing the countries.

Comment: I tried that, but it still doesn't show for me! So frustrating. Is it something that may be wrong with my system... or how I downloaded the json?

Comment: @SandraW If my advices from the previous comments fail try to upload the files to http://pastebin.com/ and provide the links here.

Comment: Ah! I searched and searched and the JavaScript console (which being a beginner, I didn't know about) said my the urls were somehow not working. The links required that http be in the statement. Thanks for your help! Much appreciated :)

Comment: @SandraW Nice to know that my answer and comments were helpful. It would be nice if you upvote my answer or mark it as correct.